# Let $F$ be a field. Show that there exist at most two solutions of $x^2 = 1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $F$ be a field. Show that there exist at most two solutions of $$x^2 = 1.$$

I am stuck at finding a proof for this statement. The textbook introduces a theorem that there exists a unique positive number y such that $$y^n = x$$
but it does not state anything else about number of solutions. How can tackle this question properly? 
Thank you.

Comment: More general (but more difficult to prove) : A polynomial of degree $d$ over a field has at most $d$ roots.

Comment: I agree it would be more difficult. I think there is a better way to prove a short question like this. Do you agree, Peter?

Comment: In fact, the special case $x^2=1$ can be done easier because you can easily factor $x^2-1$

Answer (score 5):

$x^2=1$ is equivalent to $(x-1)(x+1)=0$

In a field a product is $0$ if and only if one of the factors is $0$, hence $x-1$ or $x+1$ must be $0$, hence there are at most $2$ solutions.

Comment: That makes sense. But is it possible to have only one solution? Just a random thought.

Comment: Yes, for example in $\mathbb Z_2$

Comment: could you please elaborate more?

Comment: In a ring with zero-divisors, $ab=0$ is possible even when $a\ne 0$ and $b\ne 0$. In this case, we can have more solutions. In $\mathbb Z_8$, you have $4$ solutions, for example. But in a field, there are no zero-divisors because every non-zero element is a unit and $ab=0$ with $a\ne 0$ implies $b=0$ (Just multiply with $a^{-1}$ from the left)